# Creating Redux Middleware with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I want to get the state with type checking in my redux middleware. Using Typescript 2.6.2, I can readily create a redux middleware as follows:

```
import { Middleware, MiddlewareAPI, Dispatch } from 'redux';
import { IState } from '~/shared/rootReducer';

const logger: Middleware = 
    <S>({ getState }: MiddlewareAPI<S>) => (next: Dispatch<S>) => (action: any) => {
    console.log(action);
    next(action);
};

export default logger;
```

I'd like to do `const { songs } = getState();` with typechecking, but I can't infer the type of `S` to be of `IState`, which is the type of my root reducer. Attempting to do `const logger: Middleware = <S extends IState>` gives me this error:

`Type 'S' is not assignable to type 'IState'.`

I've also tried creating a method that returns `state is IState`, but that failed as well. And I could do this:

```
const state = <IState><any>getState();
```

But I really rather not.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand TS in version `redux@^3.7.2` it is not possible to have your state typed within the middleware. The following is a workaround and you need to cast the middlewares in `applyMiddlewares`.

#### `Middleware`

```
import { MiddlewareAPI, Dispatch, Action } from 'redux';
import { IState } from '~/shared/rootReducer';

const logger = (api: MiddlewareAPI<IState>) => {
  const { songs } = api.getState();
  return (next: Dispatch<IState>) => (action: Action) => {
    return next(action);
  };
};

export default logger;
```

`logger` is not of type `Middleware` since it's not generic over `S` because we closed `<S>` by specifying the concrete `IState`. `applyMiddleware` is expecting `Middleware[]` hence the cast.

#### `Setup`

```
applyMiddleware(...middlewares as Middleware[]);
```

Comment: Doesn't work, because I get the following error in `applyMiddleware(..middewares)`: `Type 'S' is not assignable to type 'IState'.`

Comment: The `applyMiddleware` function in their type definitions doesn't have generic typings. This is what I see in `index.d.ts`: `export function applyMiddleware(...middlewares: Middleware[]): GenericStoreEnhancer;`, which would explain the error of `TS2558: Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.` that I'm getting

Comment: You're right, I checked it also. Give me a sec. I was also missing a brace `};`

Comment: For now you cast `applyMiddleware(...middlewares as Middleware[])` and get on with it. Version 4.0 of `redux` has new TS definitions. I'll spend some more time on it and get back with a better solution.

Comment: The `MiddlewareAPI` signature has changed and should now be `MiddlewareAPI<Dispatch, IState>`